# Need help querying a database to show latest versions

Tags: mysql, database

I working with a mysql database with a table called Page. Is there any way to only pull the latest version from each page?

```
ID      Page Title      Version
0001    Homepage        1
0002    Homepage        2
0003    Homepage        3
0004    Contact         1
0005    Contact         2
0006    Basket          1
0007    Basket          2
0008    Basket          3
0009    Basket          4
```

**What I need:**

```
ID      Page Title      Version
0003    Homepage        3
0005    Contact         2
0009    Basket          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) and [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), as follows:

```
 SELECT MAX(ID)
        ,PageTtile
        ,MAX(version)
    FROM Page
    GROUP BY PageTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use row_number() as follows

```
    SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Row_Number() over (partition by Title order by Version DESC) As rn, Page, Title, Version FROM Page) a
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions all very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tbl t1
 JOIN (SELECT PageTitle, MAX(Version) Version FROM tbl GROUP BY PageTitle) t2
   ON t1.PageTitle = t2.PageTitle AND t1.Version = t2.Version;
```

Output:

```
3 Homepage  3
5 Contact   2
9 Basket    4
```